# Can I compile iOS applications that were built with advanced capabilities without having a dev account?

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I've recently created an application that leverages the `NetworkExtension` framework. The NE framework is only available to developers with a paid developer account (what Apple dubs "advanced capabilities").

Furthermore, I want to distribute the source code of my application. I want people to be able to compile and deploy my application without necessarily having a paid developer account. Is this possible? If not, is it possible to at least distribute the application for people to sideload it onto their phones?

Comment: No and not really; You might be able to use TestFight but they have to give you their email address so you can add them in App Store Connect and your app still needs a level of Apple Review

Comment: Do you know of any comprehensive guides on how to go about doing this? I found Apple developer's documentation to be very poor in this aspect.

Comment: Doing what? Using TestFlight?